# rails configuring carrierwave with S3 and cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

I have a rails4 app and I'm trying to add CDN to S3 uploads. For some reason it doesn't work.

When I set the cloudfront in the config for some reason it has effect only on some of the images (NOT ALL) that belong to the same uploader and on the top of that those images are broken. Images displayed from S3 work properly except they also should be served from cloudfront.

What did I miss?

Image that is displayed (broken) via cloudfront:

```
<%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:small_thumb), class: 'navbar-avatar', alt: "#{current_user.first_name}'s_avatar", title: "#{current_user.first_name}'s avatar" %>    

https://xyz.cloudfront.net/images/xyz.cloudfront.net/uploads/profile/avatar/3/small_thumb_3f4ff02.jpg
```

Image from the same uploader that for some reason is displayed from S3 not cloudfront (display is NOT broken)

```
<%= image_tag post.user.avatar.url(:base_thumb), class: 'post-avatar' %>

https://eaxmple.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/profile/avatar/10/base_thumb_john_smith.png
```

config:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']                        
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" }
  config.asset_host = ENV['CLOUDFRONT_URL']
end
```

avatar_uploader.rb

```
if Rails.env.production?
  storage :fog
else
  storage :file
end
```

gemfile

```
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.34.0'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.3.3'
```

UPDATE

uploader default storage:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

How can I change this:

```
https://xyz.cloudfront.net/images/xyz.cloudfront.net/uploads/profile/avatar/3/small_thumb_3f4ff02.jpg
```

to this:

```
https://xyz.cloudfront.net/uploads/profile/avatar/3/small_thumb_3f4ff02.jpg
```

Comment: What's the value of `ENV['CLOUDFRONT_URL']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may need to add the protocol to your cloudfront url:

```
CLOUDFRONT_URL=https://xyz.cloudfront.net
```

Comment: I also have refile gem with `ENV['CLOUDFRONT_URL']` and that's serving the files properly with cloudfront, so it must be something else. I guess it could be some `fog` config. I've seen different gems and setups and don't know which one is the good one. The 2 weird things are the url (there is cloudfront url twice in the `src`) and that only some of the pics are displayed by cloudfront.

Comment: Sure, but does your CLOUDFRONT_URL contain the protocol?

Comment: For the images that are not displayed, are they public or private in S3?

Comment: I figured, it was because of the fragment caching. So if I change the profile pic it will be broken everywhere. As I see the only problem now is the url config to find the files in the bucket. Refile gem was amazing and could work with default CDN settings. How should I configure the url? I have hard time figuring out.

Comment: I just tried to change the url manually with inspect and it works if I delete `xyz.cloudfront.net/images/`, but still don't know how to configure the path.

Comment: Codebeef, my current setting for `ENV['CLOUDFRONT_URL']` is `xyzxdfqz7khqm2.cloudfront.net`. It works fine with `refile` gem and `assets` but as you see it broke `carrierwave`. Should I change to `https://xyzxdfqz7khqm2.cloudfront.net`? You think it would work all the time with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108190/discussion-between-codebeef-and-szilard-magyar).